# call a controller from getView()

Tags: javascript, titanium

how do get a controller of a view

```
var c = Alloy.createController('win', activeTab);
c = c.getView();
Wins.push(c);
```

in controller win i have function

```
exports.fun = function() {

};
```

after getting the win from controller which is the view how do i call this function from a view i need controller to call the function

```
for ( i = 0; i < Wins.length; i++) {
Wins[i].fun();
}
```

Wins[i] is a View how do i get a controller of this view so that i can call the function `fun()`

Answer (score 3):

dont push the window, push the controller

```
// this is a bad name for a controller...
var controller = Alloy.createController('win', activeTab);
var view = controller.getView();

// save the controller to a list of global controllers
Alloy.Globals.Controllers = Alloy.Globals.Controllers || {};
Alloy.Globals.Controllers['aController'] = controller;


// loop through all controller and execute func if it exists
for ( var i in Alloy.Globals.Controllers) {
   Alloy.Globals.Controllers[i].fun && Alloy.Globals.Controllers[i].fun();
}
```

Comment: this will work , but i already have large code base which i cannot change all to add controllers , the views are already added  and referenced many times in various locations , so there  is no method alloy to get controller from its view?

Comment: i think that your code base cannot be that large that you cannot do a search to identify everywhere you do `createController and add a bit more code... but the answer to your question is no, there is no function to get the controller from the view... also adding functionality to the View is heading in the wrong direction architecturally... that is what the controller is for and that is why Alloy was created.